# Identifying a Ruby module method invoked by super?

Tags: ruby, mixins, ruby-module

Ruby 2.7+.

I have methods in a couple of modules that are mixed in, and are invoked with `super`.  Each of the module methods invokes `super` in turn, so all methods by that name in the mixed-in modules are invoked, although perhaps not in a deterministic order.

My question is: Can a method tell programmatically (as opposed to hard-coding) from what module it's been mixed in?

```rb
module A
  def initialize(*args, **kwargs)
    puts("something magic")
  end
end
module B
  def initialize(*args, **kwargs)
    puts("something magic")
  end
end

class C
  include A
  include B

  def initialize(*args, **kwargs)
    puts("actual #{class.name} initialize")
    super
  end
end
```

When run, this will print three lines.  What I'm seeking is something *like* `class.name`, specific to each module, that identifies the module that supplied the `initialize` method that's running.  The `"something magic*` strings would be replaced with this actual magic.

Thanks!

Comment: Some reflection options include [`ancestors`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/module#method-i-ancestors) and [`method`](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/object#method-i-method).

Comment: It's worth noting that having two overrides for the same thing necessarily means there's going to be some confusion potential here as to which one actually runs. You may want to steer away from designs like this and instead use some kind of plugin system instead where each mixin has some other method that `initialize` can call in a well-defined order.

Comment: Although `super` is valid in this context, from a code perspective it implies `C` has a superclass, which it doesn't, so it's going to look odd on first glance. That `A` and `B` both define `initialize` is not something I'd expect to see, which I'd argue violates the *Principle of Least Surprise*.

Comment: I'd have to look it up, but using `super` to call same-named methods in a mixin has been supported (and I think documented) for as long as I can remember. As for violating PLA.. please.  RoR code does that every day, and twice on alternate Thursdays. I've played with `ancestors`, `method`, `included_modules`, and friends, but still haven't found my answer. Although you can do a `A.method(:initialize)` and find interesting things like `#receiver`, which returns `A`, which gives me hope.

Comment: like this? `method(:initialize).super_method.owner`

Comment: Almost.. except it doesn't differentiate between the class' `initialize` and those of the modules, nor apparently between the different modules'.  A `puts(method(__method__).super_method.owner.name)` prints `A` each time.

Comment: @tadman : Just for clarity: While there is no explicit super class mentioned, `include` introduces a hidden proxy-superclass for the module.

Comment: @user1934428 It sure does, but it's also a side-effect that's not normally important which is why depending on that behaviour is potentially confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first attempt was to call `super_method` to get all the initializers up the stack:

```rb
module A
  def initialize
    A # return for comparison
  end
end

module B
  def initialize
    B
  end
end

class C
  include A
  include B

  def initialize
    C
  end

  def super_initializers
    init = method(:initialize)
    while init
      print init.call, " == "   # get hardcoded module from `initialize`
      p init.owner              # get the module dynamically
      init = init.super_method  # keep getting the super method
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
>> C.new.super_initializers
C == C
B == B
A == A
 == BasicObject
```

---

Second idea is to use `Module.nesting`, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
module A
  def initialize
    # i, o, m = method(:initialize), [], Module.nesting[0]
    # while i; o << i.owner; i = i.super_method; end
    # print "prev "; p o[o.index(m)-1]  # previous super
    puts "A == #{Module.nesting[0]}"
    # print "next "; p o[o.index(m)+1]  # next super
    super
  end
end

module B
  def initialize
    puts "B == #{Module.nesting[0]}"
    super
  end
end

# add a class
class Y
  def initialize
    puts "Y == #{Module.nesting[0]}"
    super
  end
end

# add some nesting
module X
  class Z < Y
    def initialize
      puts "Z == #{Module.nesting[0]}"
      super
    end
  end
end

class C < X::Z
  include A
  include B

  def initialize
    puts "C == #{Module.nesting[0]}"
    super
  end
end
```

```
>> C.new
C == C
B == B
A == A
Z == X::Z
Y == Y
```

---

Actually, never thought about that this could be useful, but it works:

```
def super_trace m
  while m;
    p m.owner; m = m.super_method
  end
end

>> super_trace User.new.method(:save)
ActiveRecord::Suppressor
ActiveRecord::Transactions
ActiveRecord::Validations
ActiveRecord::Persistence
```

---

*https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/module#method-c-nesting*

*https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/method#method-i-super_method*

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!  Of course, I've discovered that `super` won't traverse all the mixin-provided methods as I was sure it did.  I think I was misremembering past experience as well as conflating the 'mixin-provided methods  will be used if the includer doesn't override them' aspect.  But this is great, and better than I expected after I had that realisation.  Thank you!